# How to justify that a basic feasible solution to a Linear Program corresponds to an extreme point of the feasible region?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Say we have an LP Problem in standard form. That is,

$$\text{Maximise} \;\;  C^T X     $$

$$ \text{subject to:} \;\;\; AX = B  --(1) \;\;\;\; \text{where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix }$$

I read in a book that the solution space of $(1)$ is a convex set $S$ which I can prove.

> The book also claimed that a basic feasible solution always
>   corresponds to an **extreme point**  of $S$. I need help justifying
>   this.

A set $S$ is convex if $ \; X_1, X_2 \in S \implies \alpha X_1 + (1- \alpha)X_2 \; \forall \alpha \in  [0,1]$

A basic feasible solution is the **unique** solution of $(1)$ obtained by setting $n - m$ variables in $X$ equal to $0$, assuming one exists.

A point $X$ in $S$ is extreme if there are no points $X_1, X_2$in $S$ such that $ X =   \alpha X_1 + (1- \alpha)X_2  $ for some $ \alpha \in (0,1) $.

A justification using just Linear Algebra would be most suitable. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn´t the standard form with $Ax \color{blue}{\leq} b$ ?

Comment: @calculus: Well I think the definition here is different. Or else **a solution** to $(1)$ wouldn't make any sense.